# How to know new path after animation?

Tags: raphael

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the new path after animation, I tried :

```
 var p =
 canevas.path("M0,0,100,20").animate({transform:"t100,100"},500,"none",function
 () {alert(this.attr("path"));})
```

but alert alerts me the original path without taking into account the transformation .

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you

V.Bonnet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Raphael.transformPath](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.transformPath) method to get the path with the transformation 'baked in'. To use your example:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 300, 300);
var line = paper.path("M0,0,100,20");

line.animate({ transform: "t100,100" }, 500, "none", function() {
    var transform = this.attr('transform');
    var transformedPath = Raphael.transformPath(this.attr('path'), transform);

    console.log("original path:", this.attr('path').toString());
    console.log("transform:", transform.toString());
    console.log("new path:", transformedPath.toString());
})​
```

This will yield:

```
original path: M0,0L100,20 
transform: t100,100
new path: M100,100C100,100,200,120,200,120
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/seeligd/HCUey/3/

Answer (score 0):

When translating in Raphael 2.x it doesn't modify the path, it adds a transformation such as...

```
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M0,0L100,20" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)"></path>
```

I recall that Raphael 1.x used to modify the path, but this is no longer true. To find out how the element was transformed you can try...

```
var p = canevas.path("M0,0,100,20").animate({transform:"t100,100"},500,"none",function () {alert(this.attr("transform"));})
```

and it will return `t100t100` which you have to parse manually.